# How do I pass in a cookie value returned from a javascript function to a JSON parameter field?

Tags: javascript

I have this kendo object and I'm concerned with this part of its configuration:

```
data: {
          awardTitleId: e.data.AwardTitleId,
          personId: X, //needs to be a variable
          nameId: Y //needs to be a variable
      }
```

I get the values for personId and nameId and store them into cookies.

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

The issue here is that for me to use the returned value from the "readCookie" function, it needs to be in a variable so I can do:

```
data: {
          awardTitleId: e.data.AwardTitleId,
          personId: variable1,
          nameId: variable2
      }
```

I can't do this:

```
data: {
          awardTitleId: e.data.AwardTitleId,
          personId: readCookie("personId"),
          nameId: readCookie("nameId")
      }
```

So my question is, how do I USE the values returned by these java script functions in my code? They sort of have to be "global variables" so that I can use it in other parts/events of the web page.

I tried declaring these variables at the top of my page, outside all functions but I keep getting 0's for the Ids.

The cookie functions ARE working, btw.

EDIT -

The function IS returning a value:

[image]

Comment: Why not set these on some init like `data.personId = readCookie("personId")`

Comment: can you be a little more specific? maybe an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery so if you have a ready function you could set these values into your data object like this

```
var data: {
      awardTitleId: e.data.AwardTitleId, //wherever you get this from
      personId: null,
      nameId: null
  }

$(function(){
    data.personId = readCookie("personId");
    data.nameId = readCookie("nameId");
});
```

I'm not sure where your data object exactly lives, hopefully not at the global scope but you mention needing that globally earlier so that's where I've left it.

By assigning the `personId` and `nameId` in the ready function of the page then you will have them for the life of the page and won't need to continually get them from a cookie.

Comment: ok I was able to get this to work by declaring the var data outside of all the functions. the only issue now is that the cookie values keep using previous values (and not the ones im setting at the moment). i thought the eraseCookie function would take care of it?

Comment: So you're erasing the cookie, setting the value, and then trying to read from the value and not getting the value you set?

Comment: yup. erase, set, and i get the value from the previous run

Comment: Have you tried checking in your dev tools to see what happens to the cookie after each operation? I'll look at it right now

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuclearghost/LXaf6/) and it looks like it's doing what I would expect